# How to Find Unmatched Query to compare by more than one field

Tags: sql-server

please I am trying to select only the category names that are not in the voter session table where the EID is the same and also the voterID equals VID-2146. I have tried (LEFT JOIN on Name and Category IS NULL ) but seems not to work

```
Categories table
-----------------------
EID   Name  
----------------------       
16.17 Finance
16.17 President
16.17 Secretary
16.17 Treasurer

VotersSession table
----------------------
EID   VoterID    Category 
-------------------------
16.17 VID-2146   Finance
16.17 VID-2146   President
16.17 VID-3159   President
```

I tried this query
    $sql="SELECT Name FROM Categories LEFT JOIN VotersSession ON Name=Category WHERE Categories.EID='".$_SESSION['eID']."'";
and it works perfectly but the issue is the voters id needs to be checked against the one in session: $_SESSION['uID']

Comment: Post the query that you've tried, because I expect it only requires a small adjustment on how you're joining the tables. Note: Your requirements should basically all be in the LEFT JOIN... e.g. `ON Categories.Name = VotersSession.Category AND Categories.EID = VotersSession.EID AND VotersSession.VoterID = 'VID-2146' WHERE VotersSession.Category IS NULL` or something like that.

Comment: Thanks very much. it worked perfectly